# How to remove multiple consecutive white space in Prolog using only get0 predicate

Tags: prolog

I have a program that read a string from the input and removes the multiples blank spaces between words changing them into single withe space using both **get0** and **get** predicate:

```
squeeze :- get0(C),    
           put(C),     
           dorest(C).  

dorest(46).   

dorest(32) :- !,       
              get(C),  
              put(C),  
              dorest(C).  

dorest(Letter) :- squeeze.
```

This is pretty simple, now I have an exercise that ask mw to create a new version of the previous program that **use only get0 built in predicate**

I am finding some difficulties with this version.

This is my personal solution of the problem (that don't work well):

```
squeeze2 :- NumBlank is 0,  % At the beginning of a word the number of blank character is 0
            get0(Char),     % Read a character that could be a blank
            %put(Char),
            dorest2(Char, NumBlank).

dorest2(46, _) :- !.        % If the read character is a full stop character the program end

% Read a white space but the number of white space is 1
dorest2(32, NumBlank) :- !,
                         NumBlankUpdated is NumBlank + 1,   % Update the number of blanks
                         NumBlankUpdated < 2,               % The number of blank have to be at most 1
                         put(32),                           % Print a white space
                         get0(Char),                        % Read a character
                         dorest2(Char, NumBlankUpdated).    % Call dorest2

% Read a white space but the number of white space is > 1:
dorest2(32, NumBlank) :- !,
                         NumBlankUpdated is NumBlank + 1,   % Update the number of blanks
                         NumBlankUpdated >= 2,          % The number of blanks is >1
                         get0(Char),                % Read a character and don't print anything
                         dorest2(Char, NumBlankUpdated).    % Call dorest2

% Id the read character it is a letter (not a blank) print it
dorest2(Letter2, NumBlank) :- !,
                              put(Letter2),
                              squeeze2. % Read an other character that could be a blank
```

My idea to solve it using only the **get0** predicate involves count the number of white spaces, and based on that value do different things

The **squeeze2** predicate is called when **a new word begin** so the number of consecutive withe spaces found it is 0. It read a character from the input and call the **dorest2/2** predicate.

Now I have divided into 4 differents cases the **dorest2/2** predicate and using the cut operator these cases are mutually exclusive (like a procedural if):

1) The **FIRST CASE** it is related at the **read of a full stop** character (the '.' character) that corresponds at the end of the program.

2) The **SECOND CASE** it is related at the **read of the first blank character between 2 words** so this single white space have to be print by put predicate. In this case there is an update of the counter that count the number of the sequentual white characters.
Then, another character is read.

3) The: **THIRD CASE** it is realated to the situaion in which the program **read a second consecutive white character**, in this case this withe character it is not print and another character is read and the white character counter is updated with the new number of sequential white characters found.

4) The **FOURTH CASE** it is related to the situaion in which the program **read a character that is not a white space or a full stop character** so this character have to be a **letter** and this means that a new word is beginning. So simply have to print this letter (by the put) and call the **squeeze2** predicate that reset to 0 the sequential white character counter and read a new character

The problem is that in the multiple consecutive blanks characters don't work.

If I perform a query like these work well:

**STRING WITHOUT NOT BLANK CHARACTER:**

```
[debug] [2]  ?- squeeze2.
|: ciao.
ciao
true.
```

This work well.

**STRING THAT CONTAINS ONLY SINGLE WHITE CHARACTERS BETWEEN WORDS:**

```
[debug] [2]  ?- squeeze2.
|: ciao.
ciao
true.
```

This also work well

But in this situation I have an error:

**STRING THAT CONTAINS MULTIPLE WHITHE CHARACTWERS BETWEEN WORDS:**

```
[debug] [2]  ?- squeeze2.
|    multiple         blanks characters.
multiple 
false.

ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
ERROR: blanks 
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: characters .
```

It seems that the problem is in the **THIRD CASE** but I am not understanding where is the error because this case seems to me very simple: if the counter of consecutive white characters is > 1 then don't print anything and continue to write untill a new word begin.

Where is the problem? Someone can help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some code working, that shows an alternative for *representing* character constants, instead of numeric codes:

```
squeeze2 :-
    get0(C),
    squeeze2(C, 0).

squeeze2(C, N) :-
    (   [C] == "."
    ->  true
    ;   (   [C] == " "
        ->  (   N == 0
            ->  put(C)
            ;   true
            ),
            get0(D),
            squeeze2(D, 1)
        ;   put(C),
            get0(D),
            squeeze2(D, 0)
        )
    ).
```

It boils down to a single character lookahead.

About your code: the problem it's the cut after the first space matching

```
dorest2(32, NumBlank) :- !,  % remove this
   ...
```

after cut deletion it works:

```
?- squeeze2.
|: a    b     c  .
a b c 
true .
```

Comment: Tnx so much !!! later, a clear mind, I will study your alternative solution. Now I have only one question related to your correction of my solution. I have to delete the cut from the first dorest2(32, NumBlank) because I have two different version of this rule that read the white space (one for the first blank and another for consecutivef blak spaces)
So, if I have the cut in the first one and it fail (because the blank counter is >=2) then it is impossible to execute the other dorest2(32, NumBlank) that don't print the spaces...is this one the reason? TNX :-)

Comment: Yes, I think that's the cause.